# FB API returning blank for /statuses while result is in /feed

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all the data the logged-in user / one of his friends posted on FB.
I'm currently doing three different calls to:

1. `/<username I want data for>/links`
2. `/<username I want data for>/photos/uploaded`
3. `/<username I want data for>/statuses`

This works just fine for many users. However, some users are returning an empty result (`{
  "data": [
  ]
}`). When trying to debug I'm noticing that a call to `/username/feed` is returning results which some of them are links / photos / statuses.

How can this be? Am I calling the wrong endpoints?

This is the relevant API page [FB User Object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting data for your account. Please try to reproduce the same on different browser.

(check the same thing on IE)

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough on the API call. when I wrote username I actually meant it's the <username> of the person I'm trying to fetch data for. What should be different in IE?

Comment: Because the signed request only you will get on the entry point of your app.. May be you are trying to access the user data on other pages(which is not same as your page tab url set in fb setting).. hence sometime you can get those data in FF.. but in IE you will not.

Comment: Then check the usernames which you are putting has authorized an app and granted the required permissions.